# Setting up Gmail and Thunderbird in 11.10

Tags: 11.10, thunderbird, proxy, connection, gmail

I am trying to setup my Gmail with Thunderbird. I put in the details, the **imap** and **smtp** settings were filled in automatically. They were correct I checked.

Initially when I clicked on done, to create a new account, Thunderbird gave an alert telling me either the username or password is invalid. However, it was not.

So I restarted Thunderbird and tried to load my Gmail automatically the next time and I get this error that "**Thunderbird can not connect to the mail server, connection refused**".

I am in college, so I am behind a proxy server. The settings are set at use system proxy settings, just like in Firefox but I need to authenticate the proxy. How do I do it? I tried automatic configuration and no proxy settings, no change. How do I go about this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is like mine in the university, that the college doesn't want you to email by a non-college-e-mail-address. At my University IMAP, SMTP, POP3 is completely blocked. If your config is correct (try at home) you will not stand any chance of getting this working in the college i think. In the browser you log in with html, no pop3 or IMAP is needed, so it works.

Comment: It's a shame you have to do this but still a good workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to connect to the Internet and access web sites using Firefox?

If yes, system proxy settings should work.

If you need an authentication for proxy server, try with Manual Proxy settings Radio button and give the proxy server and port details.

You can get this information from **Firefox** → **Preferences** → **Advanced** → **Network**.

Now when Thunderbird starts again, it may ask for proxy authentication and you can give your `username` and `password` for proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

you should have to enter your  complete e mail not your user id of gmail Account . please verify it one more time along with caps lock verification .